# best option for caching data in ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I am trying to find the best option for caching multiple string values with the ios system.

The two I have found so far are NSCache and NSDictionary however from what I have read NSCache will dump data if you start to have trouble with your memory and well quite frankly I dont fully understand NSDictionary.

So I am wondering what if any other options there are out there that will suite what I am trying to achive.. for instance maybe using core data / local sqlite etc? basically the plan is to get information from a online database, store some of the more important information on the phone that is only ever updated when the version number (and int) on the database has changed, the I will flush my cache and update it with the new information.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it seems as though every time you have a new version on your server, you want to download the new data, and store some of it to the device.

If that's the case, you can write all the data to a file, and save it on the phone, and then reload the data that you need from that file later. I personally like using [NSCoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for this, as it let's you store data easily to a file, and then read it back later when you need it. You don't even need to read all of the data at once, just what you need at what time, which can help with memory issues. You can also make your own custom objects `NSCoding` compliant, and it becomes even easier to store data!

I would suggest trying `NSCoding` out. There are also tons of tutorials out there to help you figure it out.

Also, [NSDictionaries](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) are super easy to use. You give it an `object` and a `key` to store it with, and when you want the `object` back, simply give the `NSDictionary` the `key`, and you'll get the object back.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Thanks dude, I am definatly going to check out NSCoding now :) havent even heard of it till now :P

With regards to NSDictionary Im not quite sure it fits my needs as I would like to sort my values in different ways once I have them in my possession.

At the end of the day I'm going to have to try each out to see what fits bets, hence why I was looking for different opinions etc, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's the best part about `NSDictionaries`, you need only order the `key`'s that you store the object with. They are awesome!

Comment: In regards to that, say for instance if you want to change the order of your saved strings to alphabetical descending ascending etc.. is that possible with NSDictionaries or are you only able to sort by the key?

Comment: `NSDictionaries` only store the data, and an associated `key`. There is no "ordering" in an `NSDictionary`, and all of the ordering of the memory is done for you. Therefore, you need only store the `key`'s in an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, and order the `key`'s whatever way you want. Also, you should accept the answer so that others can use it later!